# Black/brown substance from/in cold water

Tags: water, pipe

Noticed some dark substance which comes out from faucets. Wonder what it might be and what I should do next.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depending on where your water comes from - either test it (private well/source) or request the test results (most public systems test regularly and those results are public, or at least available to people who pay for water service.)

Comment: To determine if this dark material is mold or algae (as opposed to mineral), immerse a sample in bleach solution. Bleach will decolorize mold or algae but will not affect the color of minerals.

Answer (score 1):

Probably algae - not sure I'd do anything.  You can get a bag fill it with white vinegar and tie it around your shower head and leave it over night.

Comment: My main concern is to make sure it is not something coming from water supply. I.e. it is not something we drink...

Answer (score 1):

I would first try bleach rather than vinegar. This looks like it could be mold and bleach kills mold very effectively.

We use the same brand of shower head, ours being hand holdable on a flexible line. We use them for years and don't get that brown deposit. If yours is hand holdable, let it hang down in a bowl of bleach in water. First try 1/8 cup in 1 qt water. Use an old tooth brush to dislodge the deposits on the outside and then rinse it away before you immerse the head in the bleach solution. Or just let it hang in the bleach as is and see what happens.

As the first treatment scrub away the dark deposits with a paper towel soaked in detergent solution, then immerse the head in bleach or vinegar for an hour or two.